# Inverse of a partitioned matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the inverse of the following partitioned matrix?

$$\begin{bmatrix}2C_{k\times k} & \mathbb{1}_{k\times 1}\\\mathbb{1}^T & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

I am having trouble because all the formula that I found require the lower-right block matrix to be non-singular, which is the case here.

**Update:** Actually I asked an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I was really trying to solve some Lagrange multipler:

$$\begin{pmatrix}2C_{k\times k} & \mathbb{1}_{k\times 1} \\ \mathbb{1}^T_{1\times k} & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} w \\ \lambda \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

, but I just realized that I do not *have to* invert that matrix. I can simply first solve for $\lambda$ and then solve for $w$...

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't see how that solves the problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion The first scheme given here doesn't require that the lower right block is nonsingular.

Comment: @Tyberius Thanks! That's good reference, although just realized that I didn't have to invert that matrix in the first place...